# Restrict push of changes of certain files in a GIT repo

Tags: azure-devops

I have the following scenario that I need help with:

Every GIT repo has some configuration files that should not be changed by a regular developer within the related azure devops team but only by a bunch of certain other people (or a team). The files must reside in this Git repo and cannot be moved elsewhere.

Is that possible via configuration in some security/permission settings or is the only way via manually refusing pull requests that contain such a change to a file?

Or do you see any other way that once configured do not need any human interaction anymore?

Comment: I dont think git allows any access control, you could use pre-commit hooks, but they need to be run by the developers themselves

Comment: I know that GIT does not allow this natively. So I was hoping that maybe DevOps has some custom hook in place that can take up this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As workaround. If you use integration branch, you can reject pull requests that contains changes configuration files. Create new build that:

1. Compare checkouted by the build version with your integration branch.
2. Check your configuration files in the list of changes.
3. Fail the build if the configuration file presents in the list of changes.

Add the new build to the integration [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation).

Comment: Yeah, that idea is definitely working. I had another idea of forcing to pull in the "configuration guys" into a pull request when some of the configuration files have been changed. The good part is that this can be configured for all repos. The down side is that still human intervention is required to prevent such a change.